# #Python - rank text file for different users and add their results

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to accumulate value and group by different person as follows:

```
Merluchon 1  
Camille 0  
Roi 1  
Camille 2  
Merluchon 1  
truf 1  
Roi 4
```

I'd like to have a result this way starting with the person with the highest value(on a file):

```
Roi 5  
Camille 3  
Merluchon 2  
truf 1
```

I could do this for one specific user this way:

```
file = open('/home/toto/file', 'r')
data = file.read()
occ = data.count("Merluchon 1")

print('Number for Merluchon:', occ)
```

I get what I want. However this is for one user. Users change and are not the same + I don't know how to put the user with the highest value on top.

Thanks !

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to put the name as key, and then update the value associated to it. You can then sort your dictionary by value to get the user with the highest value on top.

```
occ = {}

file = open('csv_file.txt', 'r')

for line in file.readlines():
    name, value = line.rsplit(' ', 1)

    if name in occ:
        occ[name] += int(value)
    else:
        occ[name] = int(value)

occ = {k: v for k, v in sorted(occ.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
print(occ)
```

which output

```
{'Ju Da': 20, 'Po Lo Chi Zz': 6, 'Roi': 5, 'Merluchon': 2, 'Camille': 2, 'truf': 1}
```

for the file

```
Merluchon 1
Camille 0
Roi 1
Camille 2
Merluchon 1
truf 1
Roi 4
Ju Da 20
Po Lo Chi Zz 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I discovered people can get name in 2 or 3 or 4 words... If I remove them, your commands work. Do you have a suggestion for my issue ? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "people can get name in 2 or 3 or 4 words" ?

Comment: for exemple a user can be "Ar them is" or "Ju Da" or even "Po Lo Chi Zz" instead of "Merluchon", "Camille" etc.

Comment: I updates my answer to answer to your second issue.